# What do Expo/React-Native bundle together when building an app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, build, expo, apk

We are currently developing an app with expo. We wanted to know, since we also have some files inside the current project that are useless to the build, if expo bundles together precise folders or just takes everything together.

For example: we created the firebase-cli config/folder (to push cloud functions) inside the very same folder of the project.

I'll ask 3 specific questions:

1. Do these additional folders get counted inside the build, ultimately taking part in the final apk?
2. If yes, can reverse engineering access these folders?
3. I guess these folders make the app weigh even more, right?